# Covered from html to aspx page, but the menus disappeared, why?

Tags: c#, .net, html, interface, asp.net

**The Code Part**

```
<script src="/c/Currency.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"  >
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div id="Content">
<div class="nobg">
<div id="Top">
    <div class="left">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="/i/xyz.gif" alt="Dexia" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div id="tmenu">
            <ul>
                <li class="aboutus"><a href="/aboutus/"><img src="/i/menu/about_us.gif" alt="About Us"></a></li>
                <li class="presscenter"><a href="/press_center/"><img src="/i/menu/press_center.gif" alt="Press Center"></a></li>
                <li class="financials"><a href="/financials/"><img src="/i/menu/financials.gif" alt="Financials"></a></li>
                <li class="xysza"><a href="/work_xyz/"><img src="/i/menu/xyz.gif" alt="Work&xyz"></a></li>
                <li class="sitemap"><a href="/site_map/"><img src="/i/menu/site_map.gif" alt="Site Map"></a></li>
                <li class="ruski"><a href="/russian/"><img src="/i/menu/try.gif" alt="rt"></a></li>
                <li class="search"><a href="/search/"><img src="/i/menu/search.gif" alt="Search"></a></li>
                <li class="mainpage"><a href="/index.html"><img src="/i/menu/main_page.gif" alt="Main Page"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tm"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tms"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var activepage = 0
    </script>
    <script src="/c/inc/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <span id="txt_submenu"></span>
    <script src="/c/inc/submenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
<div id="Middle">
```

**Image**

[image]
Unfortunately this menu does not appear after I transform html file to aspx, what am I missing?

[image]
Do I missing something to enable? Since the order of index.html file is absolutely the same with index.aspx , just I want to see the js powered menu. please help!

I just released that when I remove  from the file, the menu appears. You may check the content of the Currency.js below.. please check-it up and let me know how can I fix this problem
PS: I tried to replace the place of the reference of Currency.js to header block. But it did not work either..

**Currency.js**

```
function CallMe() {
    // call server side method
    PageMethods.GetData(function (result) {
        DcSet("lblUsdRub", result.UsdRub);
        DcSet("lblEurRub", result.EurRub);
        DcSet("lblMicex", result.Micex);
        DcSet("lblUrals", result.Urals);
        DcSet("lblUsdEur", result.UsdEur);
        DcSet("lblUsdTur", result.UsdTur);
        DcSet("lblNasdaq", result.Nasdaq);
        DcSet("lblImkb100", result.Imkb100);
    });
 }
 function DcSet(labelName, value) {

         document.getElementById(labelName).innerText = value.toFixed(3);

 }

(function () {
    var status = true;

    var fetchService = function () {
        if (status) {
            CallMe();
            status = false;

        }
        setTimeout(fetchService, 300000);//Every Five Minutes, Update Data
        status = true;
    }

    window.onload = fetchService;
} ());
```

**main.js**
I got the answer actually. I overwrite the onload method. Now, I need to run the Currency's necessary fetchService on load time of the method below. How can I call the   window.onload = fetchService; or all function() in he main.js's below.. please help?

```
window.onload = function () {
    preload();
    init();
    externalLinks();
    topmenu.Build();

    if (typeof sIFR == "function") {
        sIFR.replaceElement(named({ sSelector: "h1", sFlashSrc: "/swf/Futura_Bk_BT.swf", sWmode: "transparent", sColor: "#027DA2", sLinkColor: "#FFFFFF", sHoverColor: "#FFFFFF", sFlashVars: "" }));
    }

    initHDS();
    SubMenuKaydir();
    StartCurrencyOnLoad();
}
```

Comment: what do you thing, should I put a trick code here for asp.net page?</script> <script src="/c/inc/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <span id="txt_submenu"></span> <script src="/c/inc/submenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </div>

Comment: can u post  a test link if possible

Comment: fixed it:function addLoadEvent(func) { 
11   var oldonload = window.onload; 
12   if (typeof window.onload != 'function') { 
13     window.onload = func; 
14   } else { 
15     window.onload = function() { 
16       if (oldonload) { 
17         oldonload(); 
18       } 
19       func(); 
20     } 
21   } 
22 }

Comment: ref : http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/onloads/ thanks to everyone!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First I would make sure I'm not missing the reference to the CSS that styles the menu's *UL* tag.
2. Next I would go to the Firebug **Net** tab and see if any images downloads are highlighted *red* for *missing*.  This will answer if any of your relative links are incorrect.  Also, you can try testing on another browser like IE which places *placeholder* images for missing images.
3. Next use the Firefox console.  *Tools > Error Console* or CRTL+SHIFT+J.  Click *All* then *Clear*, then reload your page.  Debug any new errors or warnings that show up when you reload your page.  Or update the question with this new information.

**EDIT**

4 - Run your Javascript through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).  You may have a syntax error ( missing semi-colon ).  ( NB Suggestion *3* above would catch this )

Comment: For Now, I am almost sure that there is no missing configuration or necessary manipulation while transforming an HTML file into an asp.net page file.

Comment: What does Firefox Error console ( my number "3" suggestion above ) tell you?

Answer (score 2):

Just going to take a stab in the dark... i see that the menu is mainly images. Are you certain that you have the new aspx page in the same relative location to the images?

Comment: @Sir, I have copied and pasted all the html tags and content from index.html to index.aspx considering the asp.net form tags and include tags for code-behind part.

Comment: what do you thing, should I put a trick code here for asp.net page?</script>
    <script src="/c/inc/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <span id="txt_submenu"></span>
    <script src="/c/inc/submenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </div>

Comment: Try running firebug in firefox.  that should find any broken url's and any broken code